# Java Sevlet Mapping. Welcome File List

Tags: java, web.xml

In my web.xml file I have this

```
<!-- WELCOME FILE LIST -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Which maps to this

```
<!-- SERVLET FOR THE HOME PAGE -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gmustudent.HomePageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I put this in the address bar I get my home page site and the servlet grabs all of my content as requested.

```
http://localhost:8086/gmustudent/index
```

However, this gives me a 404

```
http://localhost:8086/gmustudent/
```

Why isn't my welcome file list grabbing that welcome file servlet when index is not explicitly stated?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
     http://localhost:8086/gmustudent/
```

gmustudent is the context root of your webapplication. index is the `resource` you wanna access.

you configure welcome file like below, remove the prepending / :

```
<welcome-file>Index</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
```

to access

```
  http://localhost:8086/gmustudent/
```